# EF Power Tools: modelEntityContainerName Invalid Characters

Tags: entity-framework, reverse-engineering

I know this has been asked before, but I'm trying to use EF Power Tools Beta 2 against a database with a hyphenated name, and I keep getting "The modelEntityContainerName parameter 'DBName-ContinuedContext' contains characters that are not valid". Is there an easy fix in the generation templates to avoid this error? Anybody? Thanks.

Comment: hey, did you find any workaround? I have same problem. If you find any solution please post it here as an answer for your own question. Tank you!

Comment: No, sorry, I never found an answer, I just gave up on Power Tools -- it simply couldn't deal with hyphenated database names. Guess I'll close the question, thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to get Power Tools to work with hyphenated database names, so I gave up, and stuck with the EDMX approach. Good luck to anybody out there experiencing the same problem.